# MySQL student database

Tags: mysql, database-connection

Background School Corp. has two databases with a common table, employees. These two databases are located at the company's offices in New York and Atlanta. Client computers connect to the databases to make changes. If employees join at the New York office, the information pertaining to them should be available at the Atlanta office as well. The two databases are accessible from either of the company office. You as the database administrator need to check that any data inserts or modifications are made in the common table and the changes are reflected at both locations. How will you perform this operation?

Questions:
1. From the information provided it appears that the employees table is present in two seperate databases, but are somehow linked so that an update performed in the employees table in the NY db creates an update in the Atlanta database... How is it possible to connect two databases in this manner?

2. Is there a reference in the MySQL Handbook (5.1 and above) that explains the means for connecting 2 seperate databases through a "common" table?
3. Is this a common practice (having 2 seperate databases connecting through a common table)

Thank you for your time and any discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [MySQL Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html).

Comment: Thank you for the information I will check this out immediately